# Run GitHub Action to allow pull requests when only 1 subfolder is changed

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, pull-request

I have a following folder structure for my group java project:

```
-com
  -example
    -name
      -folder1
        -folder1-1
          -folderX
        -folder1-2
          -folderX
        -folder1-3
          -folderX
      -folder2
        -folder2-1
          -folderX
        -folder2-2
          -folderX
        -folder2-3
          -folderX
```

Each subfolder (e.g. folder1-1, folder2-1) is used by different people. I want pull requests to be passed when only one subfolder is changed (so that other people's folder would not be changed).